# Generating classes for Kentico objects

Tags: c#, azure, kentico

Kentico is installed in Azure. And I'm working with a MVC website.

I'm trying to follow the [this Kentico docs article](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/developing-mvc-applications/generating-classes-for-kentico-objects) to generate classes for my custom content-only page type. According to the article, after clicking Save, by default the generated classes should be created in `~/App_Code/CMSClasses` folder. But I don’t see them.

Comment: Are you looking in the Solution Explorer or in the folder itself? The files will not automatically show in the solution Explorer, they need to be manually added when using a web application.

Comment: im connected to the azure deployment via visual studio's open website > ftp site. refreshing the site in VS after saving in azure. nothing happens.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Kentico Event Log? I would not be surprised if there's simply no write access to the App_Code folder in an Azure Web App.

Comment: No errors in Kentico event log. The only error in Azure Kudu tools (under Analyze > Event Viewer) is <mywebap name in Azure><br/>02000780

Answer (score 0):

Click ***show all files*** in Visual Studio :

[image]

Or add [existing item](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/05/21/visual-studio-tip-8-adding-existing-files-with-show-all-files/).

P.S. Connect with FTP or use [kudu tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/08/how-to-access-kudu-scm-for-an-azure-app-service-environment-ase/) , they will let you [browse directory structure and files on-line](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

Comment: Show all files icon does not appear if you have opened a remote FTPS website. Kudu Files does not show the CMSClasses folder either.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run through most of the scenario that you describe in an instance of Kentico 11 in an Azure App Service.  I used Kudo to look at the file system and the files are definitely created as described in the documentation.  Rather than connecting through Visual Studio, try using a standard FTP client to see if the files are where you need them to be.

As I said in the comment, if your solution uses a web application rather than a website project, then you'll need to manually add the existing files into the project as @shof says in his answer.

Comment: Kudu Files does not show the CMSClasses folder either.

Comment: That seems very odd. You're definitely clicking to save ever files and definitely looking in the App_Code folder, not App_Data. Pretty sure you have that covered, but have to ask.  You may want to reach out to support@kentico.com of this persist.

Comment: I understand, yes to both. There are two applications. Kentico in Azure as app service, and MVC on my desktop, published as separate app service. After saving in Kentico app, I'm refreshing (via VS FTP solution explorer). No visible changes.